# Identification of ribbon cable connector

Tags: ribbon-cable

I need to identify this 15 wire ribbon cable connector, does anyone happen to recognise this? Assuming it’s not easy to find can anyone suggest where I can buy a replacement?

[image]

Comment: I can't see the bottom side but it looks like a DIL socket press connector.

Comment: I exepct it is actually a 16 position connector - looks like there is space for another wire at the right end.

Comment: you may not need a replacement ... gently pry off the top ... then split the cable into individual wires and pull them off one at a time ... then crimp on a new cable .... you may need a vice to press the lid back on to force the wires into the pin contacts .... you would have to do the same with a replacement, because you solder first and crimp cable after with this connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is an IDC to DIP (See below)
(Took me a few minutes to find on the digikey website using "IDC", "DIP" and 16 pins)

[image]

Comment: +1 Just to help by adding a link for readers to see example cable assemblies - was [this](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/single-ended-dip-cable-assemblies/11673) the source of that image, and you cropped it to remove the excessive border? Or did you get it from somewhere else?

Comment: Could be, it is the same website. I did not add a link as to not prejudice one vendor over another.

Comment: Understood, but given that we don't have a choice whether or not to give a reference for a resource used in an answer (it's required, per [this site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)) I don't believe anyone can reasonably accuse an answer-writer of prejudice for following the rule. I sometimes add a comment to my answer saying that the included (and linked) image is just an example, if I think there's any possibility that it might appear like an advert for one particular vendor. (Obviously if someone added an affiliate link in an answer, that would be different!)

Answer (score 1):

There is reason to believe that the connector is actually a 16-pin connector that was grunched onto 15-conductor ribbon cable. Picture below shows where the 16th conductor would have fit.

[image]